# Why -webkit-text-size-adjust is not working in Internet Explore

Tags: css, dreamweaver

```
 <header>
            <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand_"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a></h1>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar clearfix" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu clearfix">
                    <li class="active ico"><a href="index.html">Home</a><em></em></li>
                    <li class="sub-menu"><a href="index-1.html">About Us<span></span></a><em></em>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="#">history</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">news <span></span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">fresh</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">archive</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="triangle"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="index-2.html">For Sale</a><em></em></li>
                    <li><a href="index-3.html">Gallery</a><em></em></li>
                    <li><a href="index-4.html">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <em></em>
        </header>
```

Comment: Simple answer: it is called `**-webkit-**text-size-adjust`. Why should it work anywhere else?

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't use webkit.

Comment: Because IE uses the Trident rendering engine and not WebKit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `-webkit-*` is webkit based browsers prefix (like chrome or safari). Since IE is not webkit browser, so it ignores `-webkit-*` prefixes.

Comment: It does not ignore the prefixes. It treats property names with such prefixes as invalid.